# Material Design Components Web in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, material-design, mdc-components

I have a Chrome extension that currently uses **[Material Design Components, Web](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/)**. I have no issues using unminified CSS, however the JS does not appear to be working correctly.

If I use the [source code](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/text-field), there should be an animation when focusing on a text field as the example shows, but I do not experience this in my extension.

I'm *really* hoping this isn't some sort of security limitation by Chrome... wouldn't make sense that their browser couldn't detect and support their own framework.

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chrome Ext</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mdc-text-field">
      <input type="text" id="my-text-field" class="mdc-text-field__input">
      <label class="mdc-floating-label" for="my-text-field">Hint text</label>
      <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The "Hint Text" should appear above the text, like the example above.

*Note: I had no problem with Material Design Lite, but since that is no longer supported, I figured I'd rebuild using the modern framework.*

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I've added the snippet to my question and it looks like it's even failing as a plain html file.

Comment: How did you add material UI to your chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

MDC is a bit different than MDL in that the js dependent features require you to instantiate the MDC component. There are various ways to do that depending on how you are [incorporating the MDC js into your project](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/importing-js.md). In your html example above, you could probably add a script tag with a one-liner to instantiate the MDC textfield. Something like:

```
<script>
  mdc.textField.MDCTextField.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field'));
</script>
```

You can also use `mdc.autoInit()` with `data-mdc-auto-init` markup to instantiate MDC components (see the [Auto Init docs](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-auto-init) for details).